# How to loop through PHP PDO FETCH ALL ASSOC ARRAY?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

My Array O/P Format:

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [activity_id] => 2
                [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
                [activity_name] => B
                [start_date] => 2014-12-03
                [end_date] => 2014-12-31
                [task_manager] => fd
            )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [activity_id] => 3
            [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
            [activity_name] => dsw
            [start_date] => 12/04/2014
            [end_date] => 12/05/2014
            [task_manager] => Hello_am
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [activity_id] => 4
            [ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
            [activity_name] => dswfwaesf
            [start_date] => 12/04/2014
            [end_date] => 12/05/2014
            [task_manager] => Hello_am_2
        )

)
```

How do I loop through the array such that I get all the column names against it's value in a `csv` file? So far I have tried doing this:

```
$chart_init= new ManageActivity;
$fp=fopen($filename,"w");
$list_chart=$chart_init->listActivityProject();
$separator="";
$comma="";
print_r($list_chart);

foreach($list_chart as $name=>$value)
    {
        $separator.=$comma . '' .str_replace('','""',$name);
        $comma=",";

    }
$separator.="\n";
fputs($fp,$separator);

echo 'true';
fclose($fp);
```

This only gives me 0,1,2 as the answer. Somehow I am unable to fetch the rows against the column names.Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Step 1 - Write out the column names as the first row "manually". Step 2 - Loop through the array, and then print the values in order of the columns you wrote in step 1, using implode() to add commas. You need to show some effort rather then just ask for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions could be the following:

```
<?php

$list = array (
    array('activity_id' => '2',
          'ip_address' => '127.0.0.1',
          'activity_name' => 'B',
          'start_date' => '2014-12-03',
          'end_date' => '2014-12-31',
          'task_manager' => 'fd'),
    array('activity_id' => '3',
          'ip_address' => '127.0.0.1',
          'activity_name' => 'dsw',
          'start_date' => '12/04/2014',
          'end_date' => '12/05/2014',
          'task_manager' => 'Hello_am'),
    array('activity_id' => '4',
          'ip_address' => '127.0.0.1',
          'activity_name' => 'dswfwaesf',
          'start_date' => '12/04/2014',
          'end_date' => '12/05/2014',
          'task_manager' => 'Hello_am_2')
);


$headers = array('activity_id','ip_address','activity_name','start_date','end_date','task_manager');

$fcsv = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

fputcsv($fcsv, $headers);

foreach ($list as $row) {
    fputcsv($fcsv, $row);
}

fclose($fcsv);
?>
```

Hope it's useful!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Worked like a charm! I wish I could vote u up! Dun have enough reputation though!

Comment: @user3663622 Never mind :)